# is "Eclipse Tools for IBM Cloud" or "Eclipse Tools for BlueMix" still existing / available for download?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I am looking for either

1. the "Eclipse Tools for IBM Cloud", or
2. the "Eclipse Tools for BlueMix"

but have no success. Could someone help/point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Note: I have tried different avenues, and it seems this tool has been removed:

1. IBM Cloud / Docs / Getting Started / Developing with Eclipse page has

   - A) a link "Deploying apps with IBM Eclipse Tools for IBM Cloud" to "page not found"
   - B) an Eclipse install button to Eclipse Market Place with no tool with above names.
2. Some tutorials & Developer pages also have similar unresolved links to the above tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some of the links related eclipse tool seems to be broken.
This one seems to be still available:
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/eclipse

Also, the latest release points to move to jetbrains IDE:

https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-developer-tools
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/idt/jetbrains.html#ibm-dev-tools-for-jetbrains

The CLI tools have all the capabilities of managing your IBM cloud application deployment and development.

FYI, following screenshot shows how to create connection to bluemix.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manoj for the pointers... The Eclipse link contains the plugin URL, which no longer exists, and the combined "Eclipse + IBM Cloud Tools" package. It is good to know / have the CLI version available as well. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The eclipse link above would lead you to the following direct link for downloading the eclipse. The screenshot I posted above is from eclipse which I downloaded and installed. http://eclipse.bluemix.net/packages/epp.bmt/?cm_mc_uid=14955204157715435413856&cm_mc_sid_50200000=13409221544496500552&cm_mc_sid_52640000=23791991544496500561

Answer (score 0):

It appears that as of October 2, 2018 the BlueMix tools are deprecated and cannot be imported into Eclipse anymore. Following the link from the Eclipse "New Server Runtime Environment" settings page:

https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/

```
Index of /ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates
Icon  Name                                         Last modified      Size  Description
[DIR] Parent Directory                                                  -   
[DIR] apiconnecttools/                             01-Apr-2016 10:12    -   
[DIR] bluemixAdapter_deprecated/                   02-Oct-2018 10:11    -
```